# Formatting nested category group labels in Reporting Services charts

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have 2 category groups in my SSRS chart. One is "short weekday name", the other is "hours". I want the graph to show hour-by-hour change, but I want only the "short weekday name" to be shown in the horizontal axis.

I want it to show JUST the "short weekday name", but "hours" still needs to be in the category group, I only want to hide it. Is this possible?

In advance, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, you can kind of hack your way around this.  Open the Category Group properties for your "hours" group and go to the "General" tab.  In the "Label" field, click "Expression" and enter:

```
=Nothing
```

This should prevent the field values from appearing as labels on the x-axis.  If you want to tidy up further, you can go into the x-axis properties and disable major and minor tick marks.  You'll be left with your outer Category group having brackets on the chart, but it's a minor gripe.

This worked for me on SSRS 2008 R2.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Now to figure out how to make the gridline appear between categories, not in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

As an enhancement to GShenanigan answer if instead you set the short weekday name group to =nothing then the category brackets will disappear.

If you then set the label of the hours group to = short weekday name, it should look exactly as you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a long time answered, but I wanted to elaborate some more... you can also force the Label Auto Fit Settings (Prevent Font Grow/Shrink/Offset/Wrap to True) alongside a font size for the label to help remove any white space that may have been created